# A shorter but meaningful validation message for "This email is already subscribed"

Tags: error-message, validation

What are the shorter, meaningful message for  "This email is already subscribed"/ "This email is already register"

What is good ?

> "This email is used"
>
> "This email is existed"
>
> "This email is already registered"
>
> "Duplicated email"

[image]

So it can be fit in a narrow column like this while still give the clear and precise meaning.

Comment: Keep in mind that this type of specific message could be used to by bad guys to check masses of email addresses and use the result for spamming/phishing who's.

Comment: You're just going to get lots of one-line answers here, so can you expand on your question? What is the specific scenario you need this message for? If you have a specific situation then the message can be catered for that particular instance. Otherwise it'll just be a lot of English Language thesaurus-type answers.

Comment: @SarawutPositwinyu I've changed my -1 vote to +1, since you put the question into context. Now it's a much better question!

Comment: @BennySkogberg Thx, i will trying making a better question next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about "Address In Use" or "Already Registered"?  Any of the other suggestions would also work.  Is there a specific character count you are trying to stay below?

Answer (score 1):

"Email exists" or "Email already in use"

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer to an address or email address rather than just to "email".

There is a lot of conflation of terminology, with "email" meaning both an email message and an email address depending on context. There's the potential to confuse users who think you're talking about the message rather than the address (even if the message wouldn't make sense in context).

My answer would be something along the lines of "Address already subscribed". "Address in use" may be shorter but risks conflation with "Address currently being used as part of a process".

Answer (score 1):

"**This email is in use**", please use a different mail id or use forget password to login with the registered email id.

Answer (score 0):

"This Email is already taken!"